# Dynamically Created OnClick Handlers Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 css classes that are named a particular way : test-class-0, test-class-1, test-class-2, test-class-3 so that I can register custom click handlers programmatically.

Here is my attempt:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $('.test-class-'+i).on('click', function(e){ alert(i); });
}
```

Full demo:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $('.test-class-' + i).on('click', function(e) {
    alert(i);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-class-0">TEST 1</div>
<div class="test-class-1">TEST 2</div>
<div class="test-class-2">TEST 3</div>
<div class="test-class-3">TEST 4</div>
```

The events get registered, however, the handler will always use the latest value of i, which is 4, when I would like the value of i on the time of handler registration, so I get alert(0), alert(1), alert(2), and alert(3) when I click on test-class-0, 1, 2, 3 respectively.

Is there a way I can lock down the value of i within the function when the click handler is registered?

Comment: `i` is declared outside of your event handler function. Why are you doing this, why not use a common class `.test-class`?

Comment: Because I need to display different data, for example, data in an array index that aligns with the value of i.

Comment: es6 answer is to use `let i` instead of `var i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $('.test-class-' + i).on('click', {
    i: i
  }, function(e) {
    alert(e.data.i);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-class-0">TEST 1</div>
<div class="test-class-1">TEST 2</div>
<div class="test-class-2">TEST 3</div>
<div class="test-class-3">TEST 4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you might use only one event handler, and resolve the class index at runtime:

```js
$('[class*="test-class-"').on('click', function() {
  var i = $(this).attr("class").replace("test-class-", "");
  alert(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-class-0">TEST 1</div>
<div class="test-class-1">TEST 2</div>
<div class="test-class-2">TEST 3</div>
<div class="test-class-3">TEST 4</div>
```

Comment: Very awesome. I like how this does not require a call to index()!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [**closure**](http://jsfiddle.net/v0gf8h46/10/):

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  (function( i ) {
     $('.test-class-'+i).on('click', function(e){ alert(i); });
  })( i )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-class-0">TEST 1</div>
<div class="test-class-1">TEST 2</div>
<div class="test-class-2">TEST 3</div>
<div class="test-class-3">TEST 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this instead of the for:

```js
$('*[class*="test-class-"]').each(function(i) {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    alert(i + 1)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-class-0">TEST 1</div>
<div class="test-class-1">TEST 2</div>
<div class="test-class-2">TEST 3</div>
<div class="test-class-3">TEST 4</div>
```